# Unable to create new action by holding Ctrl and draging from the element

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, switch-statement

I am using Xcode7 and Swift programming language.
I have created a new ViewController by dragging one to the Main.storyboard.

Right now I am facing a problem creating actions for the elements by holding Ctrl and dragging to the ViewController code view.

Have no idea Why it is not working. Maybe I have to create a secondViewController in a different way, but not dragging from available.

Thank you for the answers.

Here is a pic.

[image: Switcher Problem]

Comment: I have only one class for now, ViewController. As you see on the pic.

Comment: Try moving the cursor to above the fullnameTextfield line, sometimes things just get wonky when it comes to drag and drop...

Comment: double check that your view class in interface builder still has the correct class set, in your case ViewController. Also try cleaning the project (command-shift-K), quitting X-code. If all that fails perform voodoo or wait from a genius here to give te perfect answer ;)

Comment: @ddolce I have tried to move it everywhere. Thanks

Comment: @Glenn Thank you as well, command-shift-K did not help as well as quitting X-code. P.S. voodoo :D

Comment: Are you sure you linked your `ViewController` class to the correct xib in Storyboard? On the side bar all the way to the right of the screen under identity inspector - Custom class, it has to say `ViewController`

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code. It is supposed to work like this.I used to have the same problem in the past. it appears to be an Xcode bug that apple didn't work on fixing it just yet. You can follow some actions like i did in the past and worked for me or if that doesn't work you can rewrite the Xcode project. I know its a bit too much but i don't think there is just another way to fix it except if you can find what exactly on your code seems to conflict with it and not allowing you to do that ctrl drag connection. Also do check if the new viewController you have added has a class under the inspection element on your right of Xcode cause that might not allowing it for the connection to just work

This is what i followed in the past:

```
  Quit Xcode and clean out ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData manually
clean and reset Xcode
reset Simulator
restart Xcode
or eventually restart your macbook
```

You can also do this but there may be some loss. Some times it helps though:

```
delete ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

Hope it helps you out.

Comment: I just had to create new class for that ViewController to drag later into it.

Comment: Ah i see it was the thing i told you here : Also do check if the new viewController you have added has a class under the inspection element on your right of Xcode cause that might not allowing it for the connection to just work. Well you are lucky enough cause at the past i had the same problem but it had nothing to do with the class :/.. Xcode 7 beta 2 if i remember correct